# How to change a function return like a object value

Tags: javascript, object

I want to change the funtion return like a object.

I get a error:  Invalid left-hand side in assignment

```
list = {"a":"hi","b":"hello","c":"test"};

var test = function (object) {

return object.a;
}

console.log(test(list));

test(list) = {"new":"replace list"};
// error  Invalid left-hand side in assignment


console.log(test(list));
```

Comment: This is actually a very common bias among programmers that your code is obvious and self-explaining. But this is only because you wrote it and have worked on it for some time. It's not obvious at all to us, so please add some explanations as to what this code is supposed to do and what is wrong with it.

Comment: @georg maybe this is better?

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Comment: So, `test` is the identity function (`object=>object`) and you want it instead to unconditionally return `{"new":"replace list"}`. If I understand you correctly, you want to replace `test` with a new function, i.e., `test = function() { return {"new":"replace list"}; }` Is that correct?

Comment: Maby you can look at the live code: https://timmit147.github.io/app2/index.html. When I am on mobile and drag 1 item up i get  a error Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

Comment: @apsillers I want to replace the output of test like like a object. list= {"new":"replace list"};

Comment: @nur this adds a new item to the list I want to replace the list. Output of your code is {a: "hi", b: "hello", c: "test", new: "replace list"}. What I want is {new: "replace list"}.

Comment: If I would you ( @Tim ), I rather use a object, like: `let obj = { list : { ... }}`, then update like so, `test(obj).list = { "new": "replace list" }`

Comment: @Nur I can not do that because my function test can return different outcomes in my code like object.a or object.a.c.d

Comment: @Tim, what are you trying to do exactly? Can you give us an example?

Comment: @Nur This is my code https://github.com/timmit147/app2 this is the website https://github.com/timmit147/app2 when I drag a item up on mobile I want it to change the order of the object.

Comment: @Nur https://github.com/timmit147/app2/blob/main/modules/script.js line 125